# the 500 error of spring boot orderRepository.save(order);

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Method in `OrderService`:

```java
@Transactional
public void createOrder(Long userId, Long itemId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    try {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found"));

        ItemEntity item = itemRepository.findById(itemId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Item not found"));

        item.setQteInStock(item.getQteInStock() - 1);
        user.setItemEntities((Collection<ItemEntity>) item);

        OrderEntity order = new OrderEntity();
        order.setUser(user);
        order.setItem(item);
        order.setDateObtained(LocalDateTime.now());
        order.setDateReturned(null);

        orderRepository.save(order);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        // Handle the exception and possibly rethrow or log it
        // Decide whether to commit or rollback the transaction based on your application logic
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle other exceptions and log them
        // Rollback might occur automatically for unchecked exceptions
        // Decide whether to commit or rollback the transaction based on your application logic
    }
}
```

Method in Controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/order")
public ResponseEntity<String> createOrder(@RequestBody OrderDto orderRequestDTO) {
    try {
        orderService.createOrder(orderRequestDTO.getUserId(), orderRequestDTO.getItemId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Order created successfully");
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error creating order: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and i catch the 500 error in this line: `orderRepository.save(order);`

i except to add the data in the database

Comment: please attach the code of `OrderEntity ` and `ItemEntity`, and also the exception stacktrace to be able to find the cause of the problem

Comment: Yes, please share the console output for exception